# Date stored in mysql database not the same as displayed in client & server, running on localhost

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, nestjs, typeorm

I am facing the problem that dates I get in a response from an API call differ from the actual saved value in the database. The dates in the database are correct but in my client and server  it is `-2 hours`.

My clientside is an Angular 10 project and my server is running on latest NestJS with typeorm.

Date in the database: `2020-10-22 14:24:08.731510` stored as datetime.

Date with `console.log()` on server & clientside: `2020-10-22T12:24:08.731Z`

I am selected the obejct with typeorm entity manager like this `entityManager.findOne(Course, 1)`, where the course object holds the date property.

I know it seems to be a problem with timezones but I never came across this before and client, server and database are running on localhost.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: You have to check fetching and data converting/mapping places. Looks that as you said it's timezone or locale problem

Comment: @Dumbo yes the problem is it comes fresh out from the database using typeorms findOne method. So the only thing I could think of is that typeorm is converting it into a wrong timezone. But I cannot find any documentation of this.